# Magento 2: How to solve this {{system messages }} issue

Tags: magento2, messages, adminnotification

How can i solve this issue ? it is weird 
{{{System Messages}}{{System Messages}}{{System Messages}}{{themeMagento/backend}}}

[image]

This issue is appearing/ visible every where in the admin almost

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a corrupted js-translation.json file in these two locations:

- pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/[locale]/js-translation.json
- var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/[locale]/js-translation.json

You should first of all try to delete these two files and then flush cache and execute

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f [locale] -a adminhtml`

If the file still gets generated containing curly braces maybe you're having an issue I also had and in database table
`core_config_data` there are records that make the system think inline translate is on. It happened to me via the migration tool. Try setting those values to 0 and retry deploying static content.

[image]

Notice here the 3rd row contains a row that doesn't exist in a default installation of magento 2 but appeared after migrating data. The value was 1 and I set it to 0 and it instantly generated the proper translations.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

go to database and verify entries in the translation table
[image]

then execute this :

to delete all files except the .htacces enter the pub/static directory and run

find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
then you can run

rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/

then

bin/magento set:static-content:dep -f [langages]